# li nav menu only firing my .toggleClass every other click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a `<ul> <li>` jQuery Nav. The usual type. (mark-up wise).

Below is the jQuery that is powering it.. the problem is.. my `.toggleClass` only is read first click and third click (so every other click). So class doesn't attach on second click. Though, it does work properly on every click if the user hits the close button and that code fires.. But if the user doesn't 'close' and decides to go straight to the other nav item (which is more often the case). Every other click; everything is broken, because this line doesn't attach     **vv**

```
$('section.educator-guide').toggleClass('toggle-margin'); // only attaches every other click
```

Below is all relevant jQuery.

```
  $('.mainseries li').filter(':parent').click(
        function(e){
            //e.preventDefault();
            $('.serieDetails').hide();
            $('.mainseries li').removeClass('activeSerie');
            $('.series').css('height','inherit');
            $('section.educator-guide').toggleClass('toggle-margin'); // this


            var element = $(this).find('.serieDetails');
            element.fadeIn();
                    $('.series').height($('.series').height()+element.height());
                    $(this).addClass('activeSerie');
                    // $(this).toggleClass('toggle-margin');

                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('.series').offset().top+element.height()} ,
                        'slow' ,
                        function(){
                            //element.show();
                            //$(this).find('.serieDetails').show();
                    });
        });

    $('.btnClose').click(function(e){
        $('.mainseries li').removeClass('activeSerie');
        $('section.educator-guide').removeClass('toggle-margin');
        $('.serieDetails').slideUp("slow",function(){ $('.series').css('height','inherit'); $('.serieDetails').hide(); run=true;});
        return false;
    });
```

I have tried every which way of rearranging where I am calling this -- I have tried to `.removeClass` as the close button at the top of main `<li>` click function, still didn't work. I have tried adding `return false;` nothing!

Comment: if you need it added every time then use addClass

Comment: Dude, that worked, mark as answer. It would be awesome if you could also explain why @PatrickEvans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass), as it name implies, toggles a class on or off.

> Description: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in
>   the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence
>   or the value of the state argument.

for instance if you have

```
<a class="someClass"></a>
```

and call

```
$("a").toggleClass("someClass");
//resulting in <a class=""></a>
```

someClass will be removed.

Call toggleClass again and it adds it back.

```
$("a").toggleClass("someClass");
//resulting in <a class="someClass"></a>
```

If you need a class added every single time just use the [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method.

---

Of course you could also just use toggleClass inside your close function, as well as in your open function, ie:

```
$('.btnClose').click(function(e){
    ...
    $('section.educator-guide').toggleClass('toggle-margin');
    ...
});
```

This would toggle the class off when you close, and then toggle it back on when you open. But this has a disadvantage that at some point the state of the class might become backward, ie hitting close would toggle the class on, hitting open would toggle the class off. So in this particular case I would use addClass and removeClass

toggleClass Demo

```js
jQuery("div").click(function(){
   jQuery(this).toggleClass("toggled");  
})
```

```css
div {
  background:#000;
  color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.toggled {
  background:#FFF;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">Click me to toggle class on and off</div>
```